# I want to obtain the minimum vale of this expression with the given constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am interested in finding the minimum value of the expression in the R.H.S. below
$d\leq \frac{1}{6} \left(4 \sqrt{a^2 \sin ^2(x)}+b \left(-\sqrt{3} \sin (j-2 x)+\cos (j-2 x)+2 \cos (j)\right)+c \left(-\sqrt{3} \sin (2 x)+\cos (2 x)+2\right)\right)$

Here,
$a,b,c,j$ are constants such that

$0<a,b,c\leq1$

$-\frac{\pi }{2}\leq j \leq\frac{\pi }{2}$

As can be seen from the plot below,

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[1/6 (b (2 Cos[j] + Cos[j - 2 x] - Sqrt[3] Sin[j - 2 x]) + 
     4 Sqrt[a^2 Sin[x]^2] + c (2 + Cos[2 x] - Sqrt[3] Sin[2 x])), {x, 
   0, 6 \[Pi]}, {j, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}], {a, 0.1, 1}, {b, 0.1, 1}, {c,
   0.1, 1}]
```

a real minimum $d$ existsfor a given value of $a,b,c,j$ with x varying. I want this value of $d$.

For example with $a=b=c=1,j=0,d=1$

I attempted to solve it like this

```
Minimize[{1/
   6 (b (2 Cos[j] + Cos[j - 2 x] - Sqrt[3] Sin[j - 2 x]) + 
     4 Sqrt[a^2 Sin[x]^2] + c (2 + Cos[2 x] - Sqrt[3] Sin[2 x])), 
  a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, -(\[Pi]/2) <= j <= \[Pi]/2}, {a, b, c, j, 
  x}, Reals]
```

but it didn't give any result. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Something to adjust in view of `NMinimize[{1/
    6 (b (2 Cos[j] + Cos[j - 2 x] - Sqrt[3] Sin[j - 2 x]) + 
     4 Sqrt[a^2 Sin[x]^2] + c (2 + Cos[2 x] - Sqrt[3] Sin[2 x])), 
  a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && -(\[Pi]/2) <= j <= \[Pi]/2}, {a, b, c, j,
   x}]` which produces a warning "NMinimize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded" and astronomic numbers.

Comment: `NMinimize[{1/6 (b (2 Cos[j] + Cos[j - 2 x] - Sqrt[3] Sin[j - 2 x]) + 4 Sqrt[a^2 Sin[x]^2] + c (2 + Cos[2 x] - Sqrt[3] Sin[2 x])), 1 >= a > 0, 1 >= b > 0, 1 >= c > 0, -(\[Pi]/2) <= j <= \[Pi]/2}, {a, b, c, j, x} \[Element] Reals]` gives `{-0.288675, {a -> 0.998922, b -> 1., c -> 0., j -> 1.5708, x -> -1.11801*10^-8}}`.

Comment: Confirm the above. `\[Element] Reals` in `{a, b, c, j, x} \[Element] Reals` is superfluous.